# WKWebView has incorrect pageCount; Can this be corrected or completely removed?

Tags: ios, uitableview, pdf, wkwebview

I have a pdf that is poorly loaded into a WKWebView. What complicates things further is that the WKWebView sits inside a tableView whose reloads and other updates seem to upset the WKWebView and makes the page count a mess.

I have other WKWEbView in project that don't live inside a tableView and the page counts are correct there.

I found this bit of code on SO that attempts to remove the page count; it helped, but not totally.

```
func getSubviewsOfView(v:UIView) -> [UIView] {
  var viewArray = [UIView]()
  for subview in v.subviews {
    viewArray += getSubviewsOfView(v: subview)
    viewArray.append(subview)
  }
  return viewArray
}
```

In the webView didFinish navigation method I have:

```
let webViewSubviews = self.getSubviewsOfView(v: webView)
for v in webViewSubviews {
    if v.isKind(of: UILabel.self) || v.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) || v.isKind(of: UIVisualEffectView.self) {
              v.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.removeFromSuperview()
       }
     }
```

This bit of code does remove the PDFPageLabelView, that is, the superView I believe holds the label that has the page number, but the problem with it is that it doesn't get removed until after a series of reloads of the WKWebView and/or tableView and it the page count is visible to the user until it's finally removed.

Is there a way to correct the erroneous page count on the WKWebView?The UIWebView never had this problem ;(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly that you want, but I think you need all views in a linear array, maybe this can help you:

```
func getSubviewsOfView(v: UIView) -> [UIView] {
  guard !v.subviews.isEmpty else { return [v] }
  var v1 = v.subviews.flatMap({ (view) -> [UIView] in
    return getSubviewsOfView(v: view)
  })
  v1.append(v)
  return v1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but that function produces the results as my original `getSubviewsOfView` function. I'm gonna go with the PDFView instead. I already have it implemented. Though its not quite perfect at the moment, the pageCount heads-up-display has been removed, but I'd like it to be there and accurately represent to pages/page count.